# ng-show with translate expression not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I would like to use ng-show with angular translate and expression.My code is:

app.js

```
var translationsEN = {
lan1:'en'
};
var translationsFR= {
 lan1:'fr'
 };
```

product.html

```
<h2 ng-show="{{'lan1' | translate}} == 'en'">{{product.Name_EN}}</h2>
<h2 ng-show="{{'lan1' | translate}} == 'fr'">{{product.Name_FR}}</h2>
<h3>   {{"lan1" | translate}} </h3>
```

The values of lan1 are fr or en dependents from the selected language.The h2 with the expression not work but the h3 works perfect.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: have you tried ng-show = " lan1 | translate == 'en' " or ng-show = " (lan1 | translate) == 'en' "

Comment: add your controller please.

Comment: try like this ng-show="{{'lan1' | translate}} == en"

Comment: i tried all of these suggestions but not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a variable called `lan1` in your controller. If that's the case, you should remove the quotes surrounding `lan1` in the template. Because you are using quotes in the template, `lan1` is interpreted as the string `lan1` instead of the controller variable.